# How to get the sum of values for inputs Tags that change dynamically (number of inputs change dynamically according to number of days in a month)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I'm trying to calculate the sum of values inputted (the number of inputs change dynamically)

This is the function that returns the number of inputs:

```
const renderINP = () => {
        let td = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
          td.push(<td key={i}><input className="example" type="text" defaultValue="0" id={i} /></td>);
        }
        return td;
      };
```

This is my component return

```
return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {renderINP()}
                        <td>total<input id="total" type="text" defaultValue={total} /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And this is the function that's supposed to return the sum of values inputted from the user:

```
  const [total,setTotal] = useState(0);

      const getSum = () => {
          let totalOfInps=0;
        for (let i = 1; i <= 3; i++){
            let a=parseFloat(document.getElementById(i).value);
            totalOfInps+=a;
        }
        setTotal(totalOfInps);
    }
```

I'm trying to return the sum of all Inputed values In the Inputs who had id="total" but It returns nothing ,also when I'm using console.log(totalOfInps) It shows nothing in the console,how I can get the sum of all Input values ?

Comment: Can you explain the issue, or what isn't working as you expect?

Comment: @DeanJames it supposed to return the sum of all inputed values in the input who had id="total" but it returns nothing ,also when i write console.log(totalOfInps) it shows nothing in the console

Comment: You should 1) use a useState hook for each input, 2) register an onChange event handler with each input, 3) set the current value of the input within the event handler by calling setter of the hook, 4) calculate the total

Comment: @AliBaykal how i can use the useState hook for each input ? the number of inputs change dynamically according to the number of days in a month , in this example i try that for 3 inputs just to make it easy when i inputed values

Comment: @YassineElAissati Hmm yes that is a bit more complicated. You probably should use one useState hook with an array to store each input's value in it.

Comment: You could add the inputs into a state array and then add them up using `array.reduce`

Comment: i add a state array `const [inp,setInp] = useState([0]);` and a onChange function in renderINP function `onChange={(e) => setTotal(e.target.value)`  and `const tot = inp.reduce((tot, inp) => tot + inp.value, 0) `  `console.log(tot);`  the console show Nan, i'm messing something here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import {useState} from 'react';

const sumAll = numList => numList.reduce((acc, num = 0) => acc + num, 0);

const handleInputChange = (inputIndex, setValues) => event => {
  const value = parseFloat(event.target.value);
  if(!isNaN(value)){
    setValues(previous => {
      const copy = previous.slice();
      copy[inputIndex] = value;
      return copy;
    });
  }
}


function App(){
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
  const total = sumAll(values);

  return (
        <div>
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        {
                          [1,2,3].map((id, index) => {
                            const onChange = handleInputChange(index, setValues);
                            return (
                              <td key={index}>
                                <input 
                                  className="example"
                                  onChange={onChange}
                                  type="text"
                                  defaultValue="0"
                                  id={id} 
                                />
                              </td>
                            );
                          })
                        }
                        <td>total<input id="total" type="text" defaultValue="0"  value={total}/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: i create a function who return the number of days in the current month , how i can make these component return number of inputs depending to the value who my function return(28 or 29 or 30 or 31) ? `function daysInCurrentMonth() {
        var now = new Date();
        return new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 0).getDate();
      }`

Comment: Instead [1,2,3] you would have to use an array like [1,2...,31] for example. You can write a function that takes the number of days and returns that array.